# How to use a dll or set dll with app.config file in Blue Prism

Tags: blueprism, rpa

I have created a WebService.dll which I need to use. In Visual Studio I have app.config file which is needed for the WebService configuration. After adding WebService.dll in to BP, Im getting an error, that BP wants configuration because he cant find endpoint etc.... is lloking for the configuration. Where I need to copy the app.config file or how I can solve this issue. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Miroslaw! You can include the full path to the dll file inside the description stage on the VBO initialise page. See attached image.
Just note that all the resources which will use this VBO must have access to the dll path. Therefore, the best practice is to incluse the dll file on the blueprism instalation folder.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7J5zA.png)

Comment: Hi, how to add a dll I know. but my dll is using app.config file which BP is asking. In the location where I can give path to the dll I cannot include the path to app.config file. I dont know if this is possible in BP?

Answer (score 0):

if you have created the webservice file then somewhere in your webservice you have referenced your app.config file right? likely in visual studio the app.config is localised and referenced as such but in bluleprism it would not be. e.g. in visual studio mayeb you make a call to the app.config as

'../../app.config'

or similar?

in blue prism this path will make no sense. i recommend go back into your webservce and create another entry point for blue prism that has specific pathing to any configs you need. in this case it seems web services has a dependancy and blue prism is unable to resolve it